# How to reduce left margin

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to reduce the left margin in VSC.
[I'm asking about this margin (see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw9PB.png)

[image]

My current settings (related to this question) are:

```
"editor.glyphMargin": true
"editor.lineNumbers": "off"
```

Thanks

EDIT: The image has no spaces/tabs before the lines of text. All that space (except the small glyphMargin for breakpoints red dots) is the margin I want to reduce.

Answer (score 6):

User 'jps' us right. The solution can be found in:
[Is there a way to make vscode line number field smaller width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912058/is-there-a-way-to-make-vscode-line-number-field-smaller-width)

I had searched about "margin", but that space is reserved for "folding".
The solution to my problem was to add the setting:

```
"editor.folding": false
```

Thanks to jps