# Is there a way to make vscode line number field larger?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I understand that it's composed of three bars, as *[this question suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912058/is-there-a-way-to-make-vscode-line-number-field-smaller-width)*. My point is to make this line...

[image]

...a couple of pixels ***bigger***, for better readability. Is there an option to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make vscode line number field smaller width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912058/is-there-a-way-to-make-vscode-line-number-field-smaller-width)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per that question, enabling glyphMargin would give you *a little bit* of padding.

Otherwise, you could use a bit of custom CSS (see Help - Developer tools, and plugins to automate inclusion on startup)

```css
.monaco-editor .margin { padding-left: 20px }
.monaco-editor .margin + .editor-scrollable { margin-left: 20px }
```

Chances are that you might be able to find plugins specifically for this purpose (monaco term: margin, general term: gutter), or just to add another column on the area that would pad it out further.