# Can I move a little bit these code lines to the left in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

the number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 must be move a bit to the left to make the code more succinct

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make vscode line number field smaller width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912058/is-there-a-way-to-make-vscode-line-number-field-smaller-width)

Comment: you can disable the line numbers, or you can inject custom css, the space you want to remove is the breakpoint space and the gutter space

Comment: what is the use of that big black part at the bottom of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot customise vscode stylesheets.
There are some other options you can try to make vscode look good (window zoom level , font size , fontLigatures etc)