# Is there a way to reduce the width of this section?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

[The large distance between the codes and the corner of the page is really annoying!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msgCx.png)

Comment: You will maybe find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912058/is-there-a-way-to-make-vscode-line-number-field-smaller-width

Answer (score 0):

The error is not a major one. I increased the font-size of text in the TextEditor, by increasing zoom to 150% and did not see that space.

Maybe you will try same to see.
Here is my screen.
[image]

Comment: The only solution was to untick the margin selection and margin indicator options in the text editor settings, which, of course, deprives the programmer of some possibilities.

Comment: Ok. I went to Tools menu, Options, TextEditor, General and change many properties  but did not change the size. That is why i suggested he try that zoom approach. Thanks